# Connecting to Active Directory via Talend

Tags: active-directory, talend

I would like to create a connection to Active Directory via Talend. I have been trying to look into a way by using tLDAPConnection in Talend. My ultimate goal is to connect to Snowflake from Talend. I dont get error message but no data shows up.

AD is in a open url as long as I am inside our internal network so I dont have any authentication key.

What do you write in the fields of Componet in Talend?
What is the Base DN and where can I find that info?
How do I specify the user? The examples I've found looks like "cn=Directory Manager" but this dosn't seem like a user name. How is this specified?
Basically how do I connect the LDAP connection to AD?